# how to get the value by javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms

HTML:

I want to pass the value from the `gsearch` to the `q` parameter. The following is the ways I make but it couldn't work. How should I do it?

```
action="http://test.com/search.php?q=<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('gsearch').value;</script>">
```

**updated:**

in my site. i want to make a google custom search: so i put the following code in the homepage. `0156290304977:8texhu0mrk` the google search value. `gsearch.php` page which i put the google custom search code in and show the searched result

```
   <form method="get"  action="http://test.com/gsearch.php?cx=0156290304977:8texhu0mrk&cof=FORID:11&ie=UTF-8&q=..." >

    <input type="text" title="" value="" name="q" class="search-input" id="gsearch" />
    <input type="submit" value="" name="sa" id="search-button"/>
    </form>
```

now, i want to when the user input the searched text in the `gsearch` text box, if he click the `submi`t button,. then on  the  `gsearch.php` page shows the searched result.

Comment: fatnjazzy answer is correct, what you're trying to do is meaningless. If you mean something else, please explain better.

Comment: i am sorry, i tried fatnjazzy answer.but it doesn't work. the action="http://test.com//gsearch.php?cx=015290304348117:8tbxhu0mrk&cof=FORID:11&ie=UTF-8&q=theinput"

Comment: Yes it works. Once submitted, the value written in the textbox will be appended to the form action URL. That's how HTML forms work when you have `get` method, it's fundamental. You must be missing something else or not explaining what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard- please try this http://jsfiddle.net/L4rHG/1/

Comment: @fatnjazzy it works, as expected. The OP here has other problem, we still need to milk it from him somehow.

Comment: i am sorry, the result which is not i wanted. i have updated the question. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you need over javascritpt

```
<script>
function SubmitForm(){
window.open("http://test.com/search.php?q="+document.getElementById('gsearch').value)
return false;
}
</script>

<form method="get"  action="http://test.com/search.php" onSubmit="SubmitForm();false" >

<input type="text" title="" value="" name="q" class="search-input" id="gsearch" />
<input type="submit" value="" name="sa" id="search-button"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to submit to this: http://test.com/search.php?q=theinput
just do this:

```
   <form target="_top" method="get"  action="http://www.cnn.com/search.php" >

<input type="text" title="" value="theinput" name="q" class="search-input" id="gsearch" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="search-button"/>
</form>
```

the entire idea behind the `<form>` element is that it is making sure that all of the inputs from the user will be sent to the action.
the form will take the input from the `q` and add it to the `action` automatically.

so in your simple case. no manipulation is required.

**Test it here**
http://jsfiddle.net/L4rHG/1/

this will be submitted to http://edition.cnn.com/search.php?q=theinput

Comment: i am sorry, i tried your answer.but it doesn't work. the 'action=" http://test.com/gsearch.php?cx=0156290304977:8texhu0mrk&cof=FORID:11&ie=UTF-8&q=theinput'

Comment: i am sorry, the result which is not i wanted. i have updated the question. thank you

Answer (score -2):

```
<form action="http://test.com/search.php?q=">
<script>
document.forms[0].action += 'new_action.html';
</script>
```